# Django CSRF verification failed while logout

Tags: python, django, csrf

I've got problem with `CSRF`. I tried to logout user with custom simple view.
First, `main.html` (I'm starting, so its simple)

```
<div id="user">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="logout/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Witaj {{user.first_name}}!</p>
        <input type="submit" class="login_button" name="logout" value="Wyloguj"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^main/logout/$',views.flogout, name='flogout'),
```

views.py

```
def flogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/index/")
```

And I'm getting 403 Forbidden - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: Does the `{% csrf_token %}` tag rendering correctly in html? Also shouldn't there be `action="/main/logout/"`?

Comment: I used that tag the same way I did in login, and its working fine there.
    action="logout/"
is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logout, should simply be a link, no need for a form. This is how I would do it:

**URLS.PY**

```
url(r'^logout', views.logout),  # Adding a '$' at the end of the url means that you cannot add any get parameters.
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/index/")
```

Simple adding a link to the logout view is enough, no need for a form or `CSRF`.

Comment: I really suggest using an csrf token for the logout (or at least use POST instead of GET). Otherwise you'd get logged out when opening any site with an image from `http://yourdomain/logout`. This could be used as a DOS attack making your "member area" unusable (if the logout image is loaded in the post login site FE.), but could also be used to aid in phishing attacks and simply annoy users.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the checklist to go through whenever you face "403 Forbidden - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." error:

1. Check that the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple in your settings.py file has this middleware:
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
2. Check that you have a {% csrf_token %} tag inside the  element. *Note that this is only applicable if the form goes to internal URL.
3. Check that the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple in your settings.py file has this middleware: 'django.core.context_processors.csrf'
4. Check that you have imported the following line 'from django.shortcuts import render_to_response' in your views.py file. In the function, you will have to use render_to_response with RequestContext like this:

return render_to_response('main.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Your error is in views.py. you shouldn't 'return HttpResponseRedirect' but use 'return render_to_response' instead.